# How to pass a property from a component to another to perform an ajax request in ReactJS?

Tags: ajax, reactjs

I've recently started to study reactjs and I'm currently experimenting with ajax requests and passing properties from parent to children. I have a react component `Competitions` which performs an ajax request:

```
var Competitions = React.createClass({
 getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    compData: [],
  }
 },

 componentDidMount: function() {
  axios.get(this.props.source, {
    headers: {'X-Auth-Token': '*******************',
              'Content-type': 'application/json'}
  })
  .then(result => {
    this.setState({compData: result.data});
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
 },

 render: function() {
  return (
    <CompTable compData={this.state.compData} />

  );
 }
});

module.exports = Competitions;
```

The `Competitions` component passes the results data to `CompTable`

```
var CompTable = React.createClass({

 propTypes: {
  compData:   React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
 },

 handleClick: function(e) {
  var url = 'http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/x/teams';
  var source = url.replace(url.split('/')[5], e);
  console.log(source);
 },

 render: function() {
  var list = this.props.compData.map(function (comp, i) {

   return (
    <tr key={i+1}>
     <th scope="row">{i+1}</th>
     <td className={comp.id} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, comp.id)} >{comp.caption}</td>
    </tr>
   );
  }, this);
  return (
   <tbody>{list}</tbody>
  )
 }
});

module.exports = CompTable;
```

This is the `Teams` component

```
var Teams = React.createClass({
 getInitialState: function() {
  return {
   teamData: [],
  }
 },

 componentDidMount: function() {
  axios.get(this.props.source, {
   headers: {'X-Auth-Token': '*******************',
            'Content-type': 'application/json'}
   })
   .then(result => {
    this.setState({teamData: result.teams.data});
   })
   .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
   });
  },

  render: function() {
   return (
    <TeamsTable teamData={this.state.teamData} />,
   );
  }

 });


 module.exports = Teams;
```

What I'm trying to do is take on click the `compData.id` property of the `CompTable` component with a handleClick function and use it as a `source` property on another component named `Teams` (identical with the `Competitions` component) that uses the given property as a source url in order to perform a new ajax request. Is there a way to do that? Thank you

Comment: what problem you are facing in this ?

Comment: I want to grab the clicked `compData.id` which is a `CompTable` property and pass it as a `Teams` property and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: So is there a relation between compTable and teams component? In react usually we design in such a way that if there is relation use parent children relationship to pass data. If there is no relation try to structure with common parent so that we can have callback functions. IF you can provide team component and its relation with compTable I can suggest something.

Comment: I added the `Teams` component which has a source property that I'm trying to pass. I'm trying to find a way to connect the `Teams` with the `CompTable` component

Comment: Could you add a tree view of your components? From your post it does not appear that there are any relationship between `CompTable` and `Teams`. There needs to be some relationship between those at some point in the app. Once we know what that is we can better address your concern.

Comment: @kwelch This is exactly my problem. I can't find a way to connect those two components. The basic idea about relationships in my code is `Competitions`-parent / `CompTable`-child and then there is `Teams`-parent / `TeamsTable`-child. So I need to find a way to connect `CompTable` with `Teams`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution to my problem. 
So, `Competitions` is the Parent and `CompTable` and `Teams` are the children. I don't know if there is a simpler way, but this one seems to work. It's not perfect, I have other problems to solve, but I managed to make a second ajax call inside a child component using my first ajax call inside the parent component, by grabbing the `compData.id` property and passing it to the children, on click. Any comments are welcome.

`Competitions` component

```
var Competitions = React.createClass({
 getInitialState: function() {
  return {
   compData: [],
   id: "",
  }
},

 componentDidMount: function() {
  axios.get(this.props.source, {
   headers: {'X-Auth-Token': '********************',
              'Content-type': 'application/json'}
  })
  .then(result => {
   this.setState({compData: result.data});
  })
  .catch(error => {
   console.log(error);
  });
 },

 changeId: function (newId) {
  this.setState({
   id: newId
  });
 },

 render: function() {
  return (
   <CompTable compData={this.state.compData} id={this.state.id} onClick= {this.changeId} />
  );
 }
});

module.exports = Competitions;
```

`CompTable` component

```
var CompTable = React.createClass({

 propTypes: {
  compData:   React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
 },

 getInitialState: function() {
  return {
   showTeams: false,
   hide: false,
  };
 },

 teamsClick: function() {
  this.setState({
   showTeams: true,
   hide: true,
  });
 },

 handleClick: function(e) {
  this.props.onClick(e);
 },

 render: function() {
  var list = this.props.compData.map(function (comp, i) {

   return (
    <tr key={i+1}>
     <th scope="row">{i+1}</th>
     <td className={comp.id} onClick={function() { this.teamsClick(); this.handleClick(comp.id); }.bind(this)}> {comp.caption} </td>
     <td>{comp.league}</td>
     <td>{comp.numberOfTeams}</td>
    </tr>
   );
  }, this);
  return (
   <div > { this.state.showTeams ? <Teams id={this.props.id}/> : null } </div>
   <tbody>{list}</tbody>
  )
 }
});

module.exports = CompTable;
```

`Teams` component

```
var Teams = React.createClass({

 getInitialState: function() {
  return {
   teamData: [],
  }
 },

 componentDidMount: function() {
  var url = 'http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/x/teams';
  var source = url.replace(url.split('/')[5], this.props.id);

  axios.get(source, {
   headers: {'X-Auth-Token': '********************',
            'Content-type': 'application/json'}
  })
  .then(result => {
   this.setState({teamData: result.data.teams});
  })
  .catch(error => {
   console.log(error);
  });
 },

 render: function() {
  return (
   <TeamsTable teamData={this.state.teamData}/>
  );
 }

});

module.exports = Teams;
```